# Jackson JSON Serialization without field name from one string row

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have this JSON to deserialize:

```json
"data": {
  "type": 18,        
  "msg": "firstName,lastName,15" 
  "timestamp": 1551770400000 
}
```

I want to get this data in my model:

```kotlin
class DataDto(
    type: String,
    timestamp: Long,
    msg: DataMsgDto?
) {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonPropertyOrder("firstName", "lastName", "age")
    class DataMsgDto(
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        age: Long
    )
}
```

I use this code to get data:

```kotlin
DataBuffer payload //this is what I get from server
val jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(payload.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, DataDto::class.java)
```

But this does not work because in msg I don't have fields. So, how can I do this?

Comment: @providerZ can you write an example?

Comment: The `"firstName,lastName,15"` String is not JSON. You can't expect a JSON parser to parse it. So, parse your actual JSON first (replace `DataMsgDto` with `String` in `DataDto`), then apply whatever custom parsing you need on the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a JSON property that contains comma-separated values. The JSON message is valid, and can be deserialized by Jackson.

It's possible to write custom Jackson code that can handle this case automatically

- [How to deserialize a string separated by comma to list with Jackson commonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62960892/4161471)
- [Jackson json property (string) to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56171539/4161471)

But the most practical way to solve this is unlikely to be digging around trying to make Jackson understand `msg`, or writing a custom deserializer. Instead, allow `msg` to be a String

```kotlin
class DataDto(
    val type: String,
    val timestamp: Long,
    // just use a normal String for msg
    val msg: String?
)
```

And then manually decode it in Kotlin

```kotlin
fun parseDataDtoMsg(dto: DataDto): DataMsgDto? {
  val msgElements = dto.msg?.split(",") ?: return null

  // parse each message - you can chose whether to 
  // throw an exception if the `msg` does not match what you expect, 
  // or ignore invalid data and return `null`

  val firstName = ...
  val lastName = ...
  val age = ...

  return DataDtoMsg(
      firstName = firstName,
      lastName = lastName,
      age = age,
  )
}

data class DataMsgDto(
    val firstName: String
    val lastName: String
    val age: Long,
)
```